# GraphView выпадает в null

Tags: java, android, график

Есть код для добавления позиций в массив и вывода графика в GraphView:

```
for (i = 0; i < FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.size(); i++) {
                    if (FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmMonth() == 3) {
                        weightDiaryListSorted.add(new WeightDiaryClass(
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmDate(), FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmWeight(),
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmImt(), FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmDay(),
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmMonth()
                        ));
                    }
                }

                dp = new DataPoint[i];

                for (i = 0; i < weightDiaryListSorted.size(); i++) {
                    dp[i] = new DataPoint(weightDiaryListSorted.get(i).getmDay(), weightDiaryListSorted.get(i).getmWeight());
                }

                LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dp);
```

На строке `LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dp);`вылетает в null из-за:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'double com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPointInterface.getX()' on a
>   null object reference

Не пойму почему, ведь `dp` содержит в себе позиции с x и y координатами.

**Как починить?**

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Я использовал для определения размерности двух массивов одну и ту же переменную `i`. Добавление еще одной переменной iSorted решило проблему. Готовый код:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                for (iOlder = 0; iOlder < FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.size(); iOlder++) {
                    if (FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(iOlder).getmMonth() == 3) {
                        weightDiaryListSorted.add(new WeightDiaryClass(
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(iOlder).getmDate(), 
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(iOlder).getmWeight(),
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(iOlder).getmImt(), 
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(iOlder).getmDay(),
                                FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(iOlder).getmMonth()
                        ));
                    }
                }

                iSorted = weightDiaryListSorted.size();

                dp = new DataPoint[iSorted];

                for (iSorted = 0; iSorted < weightDiaryListSorted.size(); iSorted++) {
                    dp[iSorted] = new DataPoint(weightDiaryListSorted.get(iSorted).getmDay(), weightDiaryListSorted.get(iSorted).getmWeight());
                }

                LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dp);
```